# Quotient rule of limits for functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have question regarding the proof of the quotient rule for limits:$$\lim_{x→a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim\limits_{x→a}f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x→a}g(x)},$$where $\lim\limits_{x→a}g(x)≠0$.

The proof is okay and I understand it. Also since we needed to divide by $\lim\limits_{x→a}g(x)$ we assumed it is not equal to $0$. But we made no such constriction on $g(x)$ itself (in the proofs that I know of at least). In other words in the process of proving the result we divide by $g(x)$ and we made no constriction on the possible values that $g$ could possess, i.e. it could equal $0$. So it is possible that the quotient we have is undefined for some values of $x$. But we treated it in the proof as if it is defined for all values of $x$. What is it that I don't understand?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read this before posting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to better format your questions in future. A user has fixed the formatting of this first question, but you should not expect others to do this for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made the assumption that $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\neq 0$, which means that there must exists some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x\in (a-\delta, a)\cup (a, a+\delta)$, you have $g(x)\neq 0$.

That's all you need. In calculating the limit of a function at $a$, all you care about is what that function looks like **near** the number $a$. You don't care what it looks like far from $a$, and you don't care what it looks like **at** $a$ either. Therefore, you don't need $g$ to be nonzero for **all** values of $x$. For example,

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x}$$ exists, even though $g(x)=x$ is equal to $0$ at $x=0$. We don't care about the value of $g$ at $0$, we only care about the value of $g$ near $1$ in this case.

Comment: "for all $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$" should really be "for all $x\in (a-\delta, a)\cup(a, a+\delta)$". Since we are doing limits here, not continuity, the actual value of $g(a)$ is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Arthur You're right, fixed.

Comment: @yousefmagableh You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Comment: @yousefmagableh You still haven't accepted any of the answers you recieved.

Answer (score 2):

Your remark is sound. But in the definition of a limit, only the elements of the domain are involved. So for the limit

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)},$$ all the $x$ such that $g(x)=0$ are implicitly ignored. In the "official" [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_and_related_statements), observe the condition $x\in D$.

Also note that the condition

$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ne 0$$ must be added, because if doesn't follow from $g(x)\ne0$.